# Can't restore/reformat my USB flash drive after moving to GPT

Tags: fdisk, gpt, mbr

I have 8GB flash memory stick. Sometimes ago I formatted it to be able to install Windows from it. I can't remember what exactly I did but I think I wanted to be able to install Win 7 64-bit to boot in EFI mode.

Now I can't reformat it nor in Windows nor in Linux.

I tried to convert it to MBR from GPT with `gdisk` by `gdisk /dev/sdc`, then `w` (to write GPT from memory to the drive as the tool reported "Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format in memory"). Then `gdisk /dev/sdc` again:

```
    # gdisk /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************
```

, opened expert tools with `x`, `z` (to destroy GPT).
Here is the output:

```
Expert command (? for help): z
About to wipe out GPT on /dev/sdc. Proceed? (Y/N): Y
GPT data structures destroyed! You may now partition the disk using fdisk or
other utilities.
Blank out MBR? (Y/N): Y
#
```

then tried to delete a partition with `fdisk`

```
# fdisk /dev/sdc

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdc: 8086 MB, 8086618112 bytes
249 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1023 cylinders, total 15794176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a07ca

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *          62    15793073     7896506    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdc: 8086 MB, 8086618112 bytes
249 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1023 cylinders, total 15794176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a07ca

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

Error closing file
```

After this I tried to pull out and plug in the stick again but NTFS mount error window appeared each time.

[image]

I also tried to rewrite an initial drive area with a test content with `badblocks`

```
sudo badblocks -w -s -o /tmp/usbstick.log /dev/sdc
```

and with `dd`

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1024k count=2
```

but I couldn't reformat it to usable state.

Is there a way I can restore its factory state?

My system: Linux Mint 17.3

**UPDATE**

```
# blkid
/dev/sdc1: UUID="675599A00CE338FC" TYPE="ntfs"

# usb-devices
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1307 ProdID=0190 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=USBest Technology
S:  Product=USB Mass Storage Device
S:  SerialNumber=00000000000004
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=98mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

Comment: What does `blkid` report for this drive? Also run the `usb-devices` script (if you have it). Do you have cfdisk? To keep things simple you should probably try to create a FAT32 partition on the drive.

Comment: Unless you know its factory state, no.   However, it is easy to restore it to a useful state.   Suggest you use dd again.  This time make the count equal to 500

Comment: @PM2Ring please see UPDATE section. FYI, I have cfdisk.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I've just run `dd` with `count=500`, it must rewrite the first 500MB, right? However, I rebooted and Windows 7 installation started (I was able to see the first window with language/location/keyboard selection. So it looks like `dd` writes to the device but those changes are not applied.

Comment: ... or, the boot/installation data is located not at the beginning, right?

Comment: Your `badblocks` command _should have_ overwritten the whole of `/dev/sdc` with its test patterns. And the `dd` command _should have_ overwritten the first 2 MB with zeroes. So `fdisk` etc shouldn't be able to detect a partition table. I guess that means the stick is no longer writing data correctly, but it's odd that `badblocks` didn't report that failure. My suggestion: stop wasting time on this device and just buy a new one.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that the cheapest way would be to buy a new stick. Actually, I already have two new ones. So I'm trying to restore it not because I want to save some money but rather because this task is interesting for me ;-) .

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I understand properly what you want.

Recently, I had a similar issue. It was after making a bootable USB drive for installing ubuntu. Therefore, I used the dd command: sudo dd if=*.iso of=/dev/sdb . Afterwards I could not access the full storage capacity of my drive (that means: also after formatting my device, further, programs like fdisk did not show its capacity).

Further, applying gparted, I could only reduce the visible amount of usable disk-space, but not restore ist to the maximum of appr 8 GB. Also, gparted wouldn't show me the 8 GB but 4, 3, 2..., whatever I reduced it to. At least using Windows, I could not solve the problem (but I didn't try extensively nor did I have admin privileges). What I did then was to delete all partitions on my usb-stick with fdisk and rebooted the computer. Then the storage capacity shown was around 8 GB again, as I expected.

Your usage of dd command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1024k count=2` won't write zeros onto the whole drive.

You said, you cannot format your usb drive. Further you said you deleted all of your partitions. So my suggestion is, that you run the following command to format your drive (Maybe you will have to do this using the `sudo` command):

```
mkfs.vfat -I -F 32 /dev/sdX
```

where X has to be replaced for the letter of your drive. You can try to write a new partition/partition-table onto your drive before, using `sudo fdisk /dev/sdX` (d to delete partitions, n to make a new partition [e.g. over the whole device] and with t you could change the type of the partition table; with p you can check the partitioning of your device). But anyway, you wrote, you already used fdisk.

I searched on google, I didn't find information, that linux mint is using a different command for formatting than at least most other linux distributions.